# Tkinter buttons messes everything up

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def createWindow():
    global window
    window = tk.Frame(root, width=400, height=500, bg='#202020')
    window.pack()

def destroyWindow():
    window.destroy()

def playerNotFound():
    destroyWindow()
    createWindow()
    plyNtFnd = tk.Label(window, text='Player Not Found!', bg='#202020', fg='red', font='Arial 30 bold')
    plyNtFnd.pack()
    plyNtFnd.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4, anchor='center')
    
    # fndAnthPly = tk.Button(window, text='Find Another Player',font='Arial 12 bold' , activebackground='#a7a7a7', borderwidth=0, command=lambda:[destroyWindow(), createWindow(), mainScreen()])
    # fndAnthPly.pack()
    # fndAnthPly.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
```

When I run this code with the three last lines commented I get this (which is what I want):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8R9G.jpg

After uncommenting the three lines at the end, the button messes everything up for some reason. Here's what I get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Abdrh.jpg

Any ideas what could have gone wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `pack()` and then `place()`. Only use `place()` and remove the `pack()` for both the widget.

Comment: @CoolCloud Sorry for the late reply, I just came back from school. Oh my god that actually fixed the problem! Maybe I should search more about pack() to understand what it really does. Thank you from the bottom of my heart <3